# Determine if two directory names point to the same directory

Tags: winapi, directory

I have two strings containing folder paths. Is there a way to determine if they point to the same location somehow? String comparison seems a bit unreliable considering things like case insensitivity, 8.3 filename length mangling, subst etc.

To illustrate, how could I determine that these two point to the same place:

```
String1 = "c:\Program Files\MyFolder\"
String2 = "C:\PROGRA~1\MYFOLDER"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code should work for files (including hard links) and directories (including junctions) but both paths have to be valid!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL ArePathsEqual(LPCTSTR path1,LPCTSTR path2) 
{
    BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION bhfi1,bhfi2;
    HANDLE h1, h2 = NULL;
    DWORD access = 0;
    DWORD share = FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;

    h1 = CreateFile(path1,access,share,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,(GetFileAttributes(path1)&FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)?FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS:0,NULL);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h1) 
    {
        if (!GetFileInformationByHandle(h1,&bhfi1)) bhfi1.dwVolumeSerialNumber = 0;
        h2 = CreateFile(path2,access,share,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,(GetFileAttributes(path2)&FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)?FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS:0,NULL);
        if (!GetFileInformationByHandle(h2,&bhfi2)) bhfi2.dwVolumeSerialNumber = bhfi1.dwVolumeSerialNumber + 1;
    }
    CloseHandle(h1);
    CloseHandle(h2);
    return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h1 && INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != h2 
    && bhfi1.dwVolumeSerialNumber==bhfi2.dwVolumeSerialNumber
    && bhfi1.nFileIndexHigh==bhfi2.nFileIndexHigh
    && bhfi1.nFileIndexLow==bhfi2.nFileIndexLow ;
}

void main() 
{
    BOOL bRet = ArePathsEqual("c:\\program files","c:\\progra~1");
    printf("ArePathsEqual: %d\n",bRet);
}
```

Comment: It's not just that the paths have to be valid, the files have to exist. Excellent answer though.

Comment: +1. Why not use `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` in both cases (files and directories)?

Comment: @kobik: I don't remember exactly, it probably does not hurt to use it on files as well (But it is required for a directory)

Comment: @Anders, Thanks for the comment. I have read the docs and noticed that it is `required` for directories, but I thought there was an overhead when using `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` for files, so I assumed that you did it as optimization for speed, but then on the other hand we have the `GetFileAttributes`. I was just wondering, because it did make some sense :)

Answer (score 2):

For best performance, you should reduce paths to a canonical  form. That is the 8.3 (GetShortPathName) and lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

This is a C# sample. If you are using some other language then the idea is the same. Use GetLongPathName and/or GetShortPathName from kernel32.dll and compare them:

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern int GetLongPathName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string path,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    StringBuilder longPath,
    int longPathLength
    );

 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
 public static extern int GetShortPathName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    string path,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    StringBuilder shortPath,
    int shortPathLength
    );


function bool PathsAreEqual(string path1, string path2)
{
    StringBuilder shortPath1 = new StringBuilder(255);
    StringBuilder shortPath2 = new StringBuilder(255);
    GetShortPathName(path1, shortPath1, shortPath1.Capacity);
    GetShortPathName(path2, shortPath2, shortPath2.Capacity);

    return shortPath1.ToString().ToLower() == shortPath2.ToString().ToLower();

}
```

Comment: How do you know OP is using .net?

Comment: Good question. If not the two kernel32.dll functions can still be used.